# Answer I flagged appeared in review

Tags: discussion, support, review-queues, flags

[An answer I flagged](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/4886031) ended up also being in the review queue for me to review.

I flagged it under `other` with the reason being:

> Has copied the answer above word for word, with nothing to add. Answer that has been copied: stackoverflow.com/a/4826010/2471423

Even though I flagged it for being being a duplicate answer on the question, in the review, there is no evidence to report that. If someone had reviewed it, it looks like a genuine answer and wouldn't be flagged.

What should be done in this situation? I can't edit the answer as then I'll be trashing (albeit an answer that needs to be deleted) an answer and it will look bad on me, but without any intervention, it looks like a 'decent' answer that would pass as 'Looks good' in the review queue.

The answer they copied from was [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4826010/2471423).

I've downvoted the answer for now, and it seems that people are voting to reject (maybe because it has `-1` they assume it's bad?), but I think there needs to be some sort of 'proof' if flagged as `other`.

---

Also, just as a side note, should I be *allowed* to review something that I flagged? That could be biased vote as obviously if I flagged it, I would then vote to close/delete etc. I understand that even if you vote to close and it doesn't need to be, other reviewers will have their vote, but it's still an extra vote which is obviously bias.

Gitsigo summed this up perfectly in a comment:

> Seems really awkward to be able to review your own flag. It's like writing an exam and then marking it yourself.

Comment: the way to ensure reviewers will see the issue would be to add a comment about this. This would also save you a few chars in flag message (no need to point the URL of other answer, just write "as pointed in comments..."), leaving room for more details of the issue. I frequently do so, and I find that benefits rather outweigh cost of a random revenge downvote from a user targeted by my comments :)

Comment: The answer has been deleted now, but if you're interested in what it said, look at the copied answer link because... well... it was copied.

Comment: no need, I know how it looks because I spotted similar issue at Programmers just few hours ago (added comment and flagged, just as I wrote above:)

Comment: I'll do that in future, thank you! @gnat

Comment: Seems really awkward to be able to review your own flag. It's like writing an exam and then marking it yourself. :)

Comment: That was exactly the point I was trying to make! I'll update the OP to include that analogy @gitsitgo

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There actually were two flags on this post. Someone had flagged this as "not an answer" an hour before your flag, so that caused it to be fed into the Low Quality Posts review queue. You weren't reviewing your own flag, but a coincidental one from someone else.

"Other" flags are only reviewed by moderators, not community members, and don't cause posts to head to any of the review queues. Even if the post was deleted in review (or everyone voted "Looks Good"), that flag will still be presented to moderators in case we need to do something about it after the community has acted.

Your flag was marked helpful and the post deleted in review, so everything worked out.