# Is reviewing answers you've edited really a good idea?

Tags: discussion, flags, low-quality-posts

I edited this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/27815899/75103) to remove an initial statement about leaving an answer because they didn't have enough points to leave comments.  It's obviously an answer (although it could certainly be improved) and based on the first comment it seemed like it had gotten down-votes due to this statement. I also left a comment stating that it is an answer.

Two skips and a jump later, I'm in the low quality posts review queue, and this answer pops up.  I obviously don't think it is delete-worthy, but I'm also obviously biased.  Should I have skipped instead of declined deletion? (I was assuming not since it was presented to me...)

A similar issue is raised in [Answer I flagged appeared in review](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255895/75103), with the essence summed up in the comment:

> Seems really awkward to be able to review your own flag. It's like
>   writing an exam and then marking it yourself.

Comment: Posting a link to a w3schools page rarely comes to good end.  It is the site that everybody loves to hate.

Comment: well, that's an interesting bump.

Answer (score -2):

Some may well disagree here but I would say that this is not an answer, or at least not in the present form as of writing.

As indicated by the present comments, of at least one originated from the answer being flagged as such, is that this is a "link only" answer without further content.

There is nothing wrong with posting a "link" as part of an answer, but for it to be a true answer it really should "demonstrate" some code or method to solve the problem.

Links break. Just a fact of the web. Whether they are well maintained "permalinks" or not, there should be at least some content that can be seen at a glance rather than a need to follow a link.

The link can always "augment" an answer, but an answer should be packaged within itself.

Nothing stopping the OP from doing that. Perhaps you should comment to encourage them to do that.

Now, speaking more philosophically, *"should there be a review option to re-instate deleted answers?"*. Then possibly so. I understand your dilemma, and you have exercised your right to choose not to close an answer you think might be "salvageable".  But the case will always be with peer moderation, that not everyone agrees.

Comment: I've added a comment to the author -- blatantly copying from your answer :-)

Comment: My question is not really about the merits of closing this answer, but about what I should do when reviewing answers I've edited.  Perhaps it's also a question about why a question that I've edited is presented to me in the review queue..  I'm assuming most people wouldn't edit an answer they felt needed closing..?

Comment: @thebjorn Frankly I'd call that "dumb luck". I'm fairly sure there is a "filter" in place to not show items that you have "flagged" yourself as a close vote option, I'd be fairly sure that does not extend to "you edited it", I understand your logic, but I feel your "edit" was in the spirit of giving a "fair chance" to the OP to improve the answer themselves. Your comments may well sway others to consider that. But I think at the present time at least, once it's gone then it is gone.

Comment: This answer is absolutely not "link only" as it contains relevant, potentially useful information when the link is removed. See [the section of Shog9's post titled, "And all those other answers with links in them."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/254929)

Comment: I'm out of here. That question appeared in the "hot topics" box and to be frank, its subject title turned out to be totally misleading for me. Actually I thought that the OP wanted to know how to get an overview of answers edited by himself. (This is already possible: *activity->revisions* in user profile)

Comment: This doesn't really address the OP's main concern.